# Yii2 fresh install: vendor/bower/jquery/dist path is wrong

Tags: yii2, composer-php, bower

I just installed yii2 (advanced) using composer. I've setup nginx, etc.

But it doesn't work:

```
Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

The file or directory to be published does not exist: /srv/www/site/vendor/bower/jquery/dist
```

In the folder 'vendor/bower' there is the only subfolder 'bower-assets' with 'jquery', etc in it. But no jquery in vendor/bower.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please, refer the [installation guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic#install-via-composer). It seems that you are missing asset plugin:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.

Comment: It seems from my tests that this package does indeed need to be `global`. I tried it included only in my yii project and had no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have executed this command:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"
```

Also, check your composer.json for these followings:

Deprecated, but default option from Yii2:

```
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
},
```

New option

```
"config": {
    "fxp-asset": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        },
    }
},
```

Then run either `composer update` if you already have a `composer.lock` file, or `composer install` if you don't have `composer.lock` file yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check your composer.json file in the root of your project. You should have a section that look slike this;

```
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower-assets"
    }
```

This tells composer where to locate the bower files library. You may need to run composer update afterwards to get hte locations updated.

Comment: This solution worked for me, after I edited out the last **s**. It should be `"bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower-asset"`

Comment: @contemplator it doesn't actually matter what name the asset folder has, as long as a folder with that name actually exists. On your local machine, the folder is bower-asset. On mine it's bower-assets. The name is irrelevant, as long as the entry in the composer file points to the correct place

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue,
this is how I fixed it-

- go to vender .

  ```
  $ cd projectFile/vendor/
  ```
- Rename bower-asset with bower

  ```
  $ mv bower-asset/ bower
  ```
- Restart mamp/xamp

That fixed the issue and http://localhost:8888/ is working well.

Comment: Wrong way to do. It will be updated again when you do 'composer update'

Answer (score -1):

It seems your `jquery/dist`is under `bower/bower-asset` instead under `bower`.
In order to solve your problem, please move all `bower-asset`content including `jquery` subfolder and others like: `bootstrap`, `yii2-pjax`, `puny code`, etc. in `bower` folder (one level up). All these subfolders will be at the same level with `bower-asset` under `bower` folder. Now you can delete `bower-asset` folder if you want.

Before you had:

> `vendor/bower/bower-asset/jquery/dist/...`

Now you have:

> `vendor/bower/jquery/dist...`

There shouldn't be any `bower-asset` subfolder.

This will solve your problem and `yii2` app will work as it should.

Comment: This is totally the wrong way, sorry. You hereby detach your assets from being updated. The same folder will be created again and be update...but sadly not used ;)!

Comment: Wrong way to do. It will be updated again when you do 'composer update'